# Uber /v1/payment-methods - giving error "Unauthorized" with Available scopes empty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, uber-api

I am working on Uber API's and trying to get Payment Information from [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-payment-methods) and getting following error and I am not sure why.

httpget response:Unauthorized
{"message":"Requires at least one scope. Available scopes: ","code":"unauthorized"}

I am using [Uber OAuth 2.0 authentication](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorials-rides-api) and sending scopes requested as below at Step 1.

```
static SessionConfiguration createSessionConfiguration() throws IOException {
    // Load the client ID and secret from a secrets properties file.
    Properties secrets = loadSecretProperties();

    String clientId = secrets.getProperty("clientId");
    String clientSecret = secrets.getProperty("clientSecret");

    if (clientId.equals("INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE") || clientSecret.equals("INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Please enter your client ID and secret in the resoures/secrets.properties file.");
    }
   String scope = Scope.PAYMENT_METHODS.toString() + " " 
           + Scope.PROFILE.toString() + " "
           + Scope.HISTORY.toString() + " "
           + Scope.PLACES.toString(); 

    return new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .setCustomScopes(Collections.singletonList(scope))
            .build();
}
```

but when i try to print Scope information from STEP 1 .. it looks something like this .. but i am not seeing Payment method scope coming back.

```
     {
       "last_authenticated" : "0",
       "access_token" : "cc121212121212OoaIitK59azgf33",
       "expires_in" : "2592011",
       "token_type" : "Bearer",
       "scope" : "profile ride_widgets places history_lite history",
       "refresh_token" : "asasasI0ILhQ82q42tUOuyginNAFnD"
     }
```

******* So am I requesting scope wrong way? OR 
******* do I need to request for full access as per [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-payment-methods) ?

Please advise .. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no longer a payment_method scope. You just need the 'request' scope to access the payment method endpoints. You can remove the ride_widgets and payment_methods scopes from your example and add 'request' and it should work.

It looks like the sdk you are using is a bit outdated, so I would recommend updating if possible.

See more details in the payment method docs: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-payment-methods

As this is a privileged scope you can use for your developer account, but will need to request full access in the developer dashboard for all users to access in production.

Comment: Thanks Dustin .. appreciate your help ... as suggested removed all and added request scope ..         
          return new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(clientId)
                .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .setScopes(Collections.singletonList(Scope.REQUEST))
                .build();

Comment: Any idea how can i pass multiple scope? because what i tried did not work .. either I can pass scope.PROFILE or scope.REQUEST ....... but i really need both .. to access user profile as well as payment options etc. -- any idea. ......... I tried like above code sample in my question .. but it is really not taking it.

Comment: never mind, I got it .. just if anyone needs it .. just pass multiple scope like this .. 
        ArrayList <Scope> scope_list = new ArrayList<Scope> ();
        scope_list.add(Scope.REQUEST);
        scope_list.add(Scope.PROFILE);

Comment: It doesn't work. I have an access token with the following scopes: `"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"profile ride_widgets request places"` and I get `{"message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: payment_baidu_wallet, payment_methods.write","code":"unauthorized"}` from the [GET /payment-methods](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/payment-methods-get) API endpoint. With production Uber API URL api.uber.com, and request scope permission granted full access. I am not passing any scopes when requesting authorization from the user.

Comment: Adding the scope param with the value of `profile places request` to the authorize endpoint results in the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I think the issue is you are trying to post to the payment methods endpoint. We don't support post.

Comment: @DustinWhittle Indeed, this is the case, the HTTP request method used was POST, instead of GET. But I think the error message coming from the Uber API should be `{"message":"Method not supported for this endpoint.","code":"method_not_allowed"}`.

Comment: Agreed. We provide this specific error message as we do have scopes that would enable this functionality versus not actually supporting http method post. We don't offer the api externally which is why the message is different.